# How do I factory reset a Motorola WT41N0 wearable computer?

Tags: factory-defaults

I've got two [Motorola WT41N0 Wearable Computers](http://www.motorolasolutions.com/US-EN/Business+Product+and+Services/Mobile+Computers/Wearable+Computers/WT41N0) with WiFi issues.

If they run out of battery the certificate is lost; and for some reason the device will not properly enroll again.

So, I've got a guide on how to set it up, but that's after it's factory reset.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manual (found a copy [here](http://www.etiscan.de/fileadmin/user_upload/Downloads/Handbuecher/Handbuch_M_WT41N0.pdf)):

> The Power button is also used to reset the wearable terminal by
>   performing a warm or cold boot.
>
> - Warm Boot (Soft Reset) - Resets the wearable terminal.
> - Cold Boot (Hard Reset) - Resets the wearable terminal and *restores all factory default settings*.

additionally:

> A cold boot also restarts the wearable terminal, but erases all stored
>   records and entries in RAM. Data saved in flash memory or a memory
>   card is not lost. In addition it returns formats, preferences and
>   other settings to the factory default settings.

lastly:

> To perform a cold boot on a WT41N0 press and simultaneously hold the
>   1, 9 and Power button. Do not hold down any other keys or buttons. The
>   wearable terminal initializes.